# Inject query parameter into dependency provider factory in Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, query-string, angular-factory, angular-dependency-injection

I want a value from the `window.location` search parameters passed to the body of a dependency provider factory, ideally in an idiomatic Angular way.

Use case: writing my first Angular app I have the app running on one port and the backend server on another. I want to append `&backend=localhost:12345` to the URL to have the app talk to that host. This is read-only, hand-written to the URL bar. I don't want to navigate to such a URL.

Approaches considered:

1. Use [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) directly. Makes the code depend on a browser, potentially breaking test fixtures or anything else that wants to execute the code outside a browser.
2. Use [`PlatformLocation.href`](https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation). The doc says “this class should not be used directly by an application developer.”
3. Use [`Location.path()`](https://angular.io/api/common/Location). Seems to work, but also seems to not offer any way to access the full URL. The stand-alone path includes the query parameter, but appears to be invalid as an argument to the `URL` constructor, so I ended up with something like `new URL('http://no-such-host/' + location.path()).searchParams.get('backend')`. Hardly elegant.
4. Use [`ActivatedRoute.queryParams`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#queryParams) somehow. Injecting an `ActivatedRoute` into my factory apparently gives me a default instance (stringifies as `Route(url:'', path:'')`) so the query parameters seem to be absent. And the `queryParams` method returns an `Observable`, while from what I read on the net, using asynchronous code flow for a provider factory is tricky at best.

Is there a better way to let a factory make decisions based on a query parameter?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand correctly you want to add an HTTP param for a request? if it's you can do it with this  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-angular-interceptors-to-manage-http-requests-and-error-handling

Comment: @Takatalvi: No, I don't want to add a param to outgoing requests. I want to use a param from the current location as the host of outgoing requests. I might be able to use interceptors for that, but I already have a custom [factory provider](https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider) which describes my host connection at a higher level, so it would be cleaner to make the decision about the host name inside that provider.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to take the query param `backend` from your path programatically.

You can use the Angular Router like the example below:

```
@Service()
export class MyFactory {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  fetch() {
    const backendUrl = route.snapshot.queryParams['backend'] || 'defaultUrl';

    // do something here
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `Location` object to get the query param like bellow:

```js
const backendUrl = new URLSearchParams(Location.search).get('backend');

// do something here
```

Comment: Interesting. [`ActivatedRoute.snapshot`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#snapshot) sounds promising. It definitely will avoid the problems I'd have with an asynchronous API. Need to experiment whether it does contain the data I need, even when passed to a [factory provider](https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider). Stringification of the object suggests otherwise, but I'll try and report back. Documentation for [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) doesn't mention a `search` property. Is that an undocumented feature, or from some different Angular version?

Comment: Here is my reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search